# how to run exe file from client side by click button webforms in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

How to running .exe file in client-side or PC by click a button in webforms asp.net by using c# or javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score -1):

No way if client side  was  not  preconfigured, for example method in Windows OS Registering an Application to a URI Scheme: https://www.meziantou.net/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-using-net.htm and https://www.joe0.com/2019/01/27/how-create-a-custom-browser-uri-scheme-and-c-protocol-handler-client-that-supports-opening-and-editing-of-remotely-hosted-documents-through-webdav/